# How to register a new usb network-adapter in os x (leopard)?

Tags: mac-osx, configuration, usb, network-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OS X will not register newly installed network adapters](https://serverfault.com/questions/41908/os-x-will-not-register-newly-installed-network-adapters)

I've recently purchased an Edimax 7318usg usb network adapter.  I installed the "drivers" for this device and upon finishing the installation, was prompted that after installation I would need to configure the device in the "Network" section of "System Preferences".

How do I go about adding this device in this manner?  It does not appear to be read, although this device is working correctly on the Windows platform (so I know it is not faulty).

Answer (score 2):

When it finished installing the drivers and restarted, it should have said something like "new network interface found".  Did you see a new interface in your network system preference?  They sometimes get labeled "ethernet adapter (en4)" or whatever number is next in line.  That is your new network adapter.

Another place to verify is in your system profiler and make sure the computer can see it in the usb bus.

I just saw that this is wireless card.  Most wireless cards come with some sort of connection utility application for connecting to networks.  It is normaly included on the cd or downloadable.  Many cards do not work with the built in apple wireless tool. Here is the software download link from thier website in case you didn't get all the software installed.

http://www.edimax.com/images/Image/Driver_Utility/Wireless/NIC/EW-7717Un/RTUSB-D2870-1.1.6.0_D71w-1.2.1.0_D2500-1.1.3.0-UI-1.5.1.0_2008_07_21.zip

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  i still haven't fixed this.  there was no found network adapter, like there should have been.  That's the issue i'm having...